# read single page .tif files as multipage.tiff from filename

Tags: python, tesseract, filenames, tiff, python-tesseract

UPDATE: I found out it is unreasonable to create pdf files from OCRed files

So it would be better to leave it as is without conversion. I still have the problem that some images are connected while others are 1 pagers.

```
data = []
listOfPages = glob.glob(r"C:/Users/name/test/*.tif")
for entry in listOfPages:
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
            Image.open(entry), lang="en"
        )
    data.append(text)
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['raw_text'])
```

This creates a pandas df where each row is the string of the first (single) page of `.tif` files. How can i concatenate the tif files (see original question) in order to get the full multipage string?

original question:
I want to convert the single page .tif files in `my_folder` to multipage `.pdf` files in `pdf_folder`. TIFFs not having subsequent pages should also be converted to single-page PDFs. Ultimately, I want a text-PDF created by OCR-ing multiple image-based TIFF files.

Therefore i infer the groups of `.tiff` files that should go together from the filename pattern:

```
Drs_1_00109_1_ADS.tif
Drs_1_00099_1_ADS_000.tif
Drs_1_00099_1_ADS_001.tif
Drs_1_00099_1_ADS_002.tif
Drs_1_00186_1_ADS.tif
Drs_1_00192_1_ADS_000.tif
Drs_1_00192_1_ADS_001.tif
```

For example out of `Drs_1_00192_1_ADS_000.tif` and
`Drs_1_00192_1_ADS_001.tif` (which are two [single page] pictures) i want to convert to the 2 page `Drs_1_00192_1_ADS.pdf` having both of these pictures text data.
The code works for single-page pdf creation. **How can i make this work for said multipage-pattern from filename?**

Thanks!

Comment: You said `convert the single page .tif files` but there are 7 files of .tif here. Can you describe the .tif file naming conference?

Comment: For example out of `Drs_1_00192_1_ADS_000.tif` and `Drs_1_00192_1_ADS_001.tif` (which are two [single page] pictures) i want to convert to the 2 page `Drs_1_00192_1_ADS.pdf` having both of these pictures text data on 2 separate pages within 1 file.

Comment: Why would you need `pytesseract` to concatenate images into a PDF? Surely that would only be useful for recognising the wording/content of the images and nothing in your question suggests you need/use that? What *"config params"* are you referring to please?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Maybe the 2 step process of pdf creation is unreasonable, but yes, ultimately i want to recognize the text of the pictures. The reason i want to output a pdf is because in a second step i want to read the pdf files with a library that is optimized for pdf input (it is good at grouping sections of text together). pytersseract image processing configurations (e.g. `config='-psm 2'`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do that by globbing for all files ending in `000.tif`, which presumably are the starting points for multi-page documents, then appending files that result from incrementing the suffix till a file is missing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
from PIL import Image
from glob import glob

# Iterate over all files ending in '000.tif' and find their friends (subsequent pages)
for filename in glob('*_000.tif'):
   # Work out stem of filename
   stem = filename.replace('_000.tif', '')
   print(f'DEBUG: stem={stem}')

   # Build list of images to be put in this PDF
   images = [Image.open(filename)]
   index = 1
   while True:
      this = f'{stem}_{index:03d}.tif'
      print(f'DEBUG: this={this}')
      if os.path.isfile(this):
         images.append(Image.open(this))
         index += 1
      else:
         break
   output = stem + '.pdf'
   print(f'DEBUG: Saving {len(images)} pages to {output}')
   images[0].save(output, save_all=True, append_images=images[1:])
```

**Sample Output**

```
DEBUG: stem=Drs_1_00192_1_ADS
DEBUG: this=Drs_1_00192_1_ADS_001.tif
DEBUG: this=Drs_1_00192_1_ADS_002.tif
DEBUG: this=Drs_1_00192_1_ADS_003.tif
DEBUG: this=Drs_1_00192_1_ADS_004.tif
DEBUG: Saving 4 pages to Drs_1_00192_1_ADS.pdf
DEBUG: stem=Drs_1_00099_1_ADS
DEBUG: this=Drs_1_00099_1_ADS_001.tif
DEBUG: this=Drs_1_00099_1_ADS_002.tif
DEBUG: this=Drs_1_00099_1_ADS_003.tif
DEBUG: Saving 3 pages to Drs_1_00099_1_ADS.pdf
```

Note that you can just as easily use **OpenCV** for reading the file, by replacing:

```
image = Image.open(filename)
```

with

```
image = cv2.imread(filename)
```

However, you can't write a PDF so simply with **OpenCV** as with **PIL** so I just stuck with **PIL**. You can easily move between **PIL** and **OpenCV** if you remember that **PIL** uses RGB ordering whereas **OpenCV** uses BGR, so you can go from **PIL** to **OpenCV** with:

```
OpenCVImage = np.array(PILImage)[...,::-1]
```

and

```
PILImage = Image.fromarray(OpenCVImage[...,::-1])
```

Comment: well done. May i ask if it is possible to create a non-image pdf from .tif files? After all, that is why i am using pytesseract anyways. Your solution is partially what i was looking for. I should have added above, that i also want to convert the files that comprise only 1 pdf page (filename without 00 tail) get also converted. So far, they stay as .tif

Comment: Maybe you could click `edit` under your original question and improve it so that it is clear that a) you want a **textual** PDF created even though you start with a bitmap/image-based TIFF and b) to clarify that TIFFs not having subsequent pages should also be converted to single-page PDFs. Thank you.

Comment: So sorry for the redundancy. I am having trouble expressing my intent clearly as i am not a native speaker and very new to OCR. Is the question text clear now so that people understand what i want to do?